# What is the fastest way to calculate the average vector from a list of sparse vectors?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, parallel-processing, sparse-matrix

**What I have:**

A Python list of some NumPy sparse csr_matrix matrixes with shape 1x5000. They are actually numerical vectors.

eg:

```
vectors = [
  csr_matrix(...),
  csr_mstrix(...),
  ...
]
```

**What I want:**

To calculate the mean / average vector in the fastest way.

**What I currently do:**

```
sum(vectors) / len(vectors)
```

**Question:**

What will be the optimized solution for single CPU core or multicore?

A solution example would be appreciated!

Comment: I guess the obvious question is if you have n vectors stored as n 1x5000 matrices why don't you have a nx5000 matrix.

Comment: This method should be already not too bad. Note that it may be faster if the accumulated resulting vector is a dense one. It may also be faster to build a big sparse matrix with all the vectors and perform just one vertical numpy sum.

Comment: I see. So what is the fastest way to convert a list of 1x5000 sparse vectors to a single sparse matrix Nx5000?

Comment: scipy.sparse.vstack()